# Install why3-coq on MacBook Pro

Tags: coq, why3

When I try to install why3-coq on my MacBook Pro, I got the following error message

```
userde-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ opam install why3-coq
[WARNING] Opam package conf-python-3.1.0.0 depends on the following system
          package that can no longer be found: python@3
The following actions will be performed:
  ↻ recompile dune              2.9.3          [upstream or system changes]
  ↻ recompile ocamlfind         1.9.3          [upstream or system changes]
  ↻ recompile stdlib-shims      0.3.0          [uses dune]
...
===== ∗ 2   ↻ 23   ↗ 1 =====
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

<><> Processing actions <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>  
...
⬇ retrieved why3-coq.1.5.1  (cached)
[ERROR] The compilation of dune.2.9.3 failed at "./dune.exe build -p dune
        --profile dune-bootstrap -j 7".
Processing 32/102: [ocamlfind: ./configure]

#=== ERROR while compiling dune.2.9.3 =========================================#
# context     2.1.2 | macos/x86_64 | ocaml.4.13.1 | https://opam.ocaml.org#ac449189
# path        ~/.opam/default/.opam-switch/build/dune.2.9.3
# command     ~/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build ./dune.exe build -p dune --profile dune-bootstrap -j 7
# signalled   -7
# env-file    ~/.opam/log/dune-4900-2cb712.env
# output-file ~/.opam/log/dune-4900-2cb712.out



<><> Error report <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>  
┌─ The following actions failed
│ λ build dune 2.9.3
└─
╶─ No changes have been performed
```

But when I try to install dune along, it says dune is already installed

```
userde-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ opam install dune
[WARNING] Opam package conf-python-3.1.0.0 depends on the following system
          package that can no longer be found: python@3
[NOTE] Package dune is already installed (current version is 2.9.3).
```

Does anyone know what is the potential problem and how to solve it?

UPDATE

I tried to go to the path and build manually (when use a new opam switch, it upgrades to dune.3.4.1, but all behaviors remain the same). This give me a killed 9 response.

```
userde-MacBook-Pro:~ user$ cd  ~/.opam/4.14.0/.opam-switch/build/dune.3.4.1
userde-MacBook-Pro:dune.3.4.1 user$ ~/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build ./dune.exe build dune.install --release --profile dune-bootstrap -j 7
Killed: 9
```

Comment: It's trying to recompile dune due to "upstream or system changes", not install it from scratch (as you can see on the first few lines you showed us). It says that it can no longer find python3 in your system, so perhaps this is the issue? Other than that, my best advice would be to try `opam update` before installing anything (which you should be doing anyway). If that doesn't help, try a fresh `switch`.

Comment: Thanks Ana, however, I tried your suggestions, including "opam switch create 4.14.0", but the problem remains.